# Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.(fields.E301)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I'm getting this error.

> ERRORS: subscriptions.StripeCustomer.user: (fields.E301) Field defines
> a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
> HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

I'm trying to configure Django Stripe Subscriptions following this manual https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-subscriptions/

My models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class StripeCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripeCustomerId = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripeSubscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from subscriptions.models import StripeCustomer


admin.site.register(StripeCustomer)
```

My settings.py

```
#used for django-allauth
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'

SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
```

accounts/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'
```

After setting above, I executed "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate" then the error occurred.

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `OneToOneField` pointing to the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth` when in fact you are using a custom user model `CustomUser`, hence you get the error. Generally if one wants to have a foreign key or any related field with the user model one should point it to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` as described in the [Referencing the User model [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) so that such issues can be prevented easily. Hence change your `StripeCustomer` model like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class StripeCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripeCustomerId = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripeSubscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and code.
The problem was solved, appreciate it from the bottom of my heart.